# Unselect all items when the SelectedItem is bound to something that doesn't exist in the list

Tags: wpf, binding, selecteditem, itemssource

I have two lists with different `ItemsSource` but with `SelectedItem` bound to the same property - "***Name***".

First i'm choosing the item "c" in the right list so the item "c" in the left list is selected as well.

Than I selected another item in the right list but the "c" in the left list is still selected.
I understand why it do that, but can I make it unselect the "c" in the right list ?

[image]

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition  />
        <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView SelectedItem="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding lstNames1}"/>
    <ListView SelectedItem="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding lstNames2}" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class selected : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> lstNames1 { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> lstNames2 { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    public selected()
    {
        Names1 = new ObservableCollection<string> {"a1", "b1", "c"};
        Names2 = new ObservableCollection<string> { "a2", "b2", "c" };
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you still want "c" to be selected in both lists, but when an item only exists in one list clear the selction from the other?

Comment: sa_ddam213 - exactly! :)

Comment: Please keep in mind that your window already has a [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx) property. So your newly created one is in conflict with the existing one. And your Name property is missing a change notification.

Comment: Thanks Clemens, I'm aware of it, the code that I posted is just a snap code to ask the question, is not my real code and not my read view model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you switch the `SelectedItem` binding to `SelectedValue` this will behave how you want, The `SelectedItem` is not clearing because its not set to `null` because the other list has set a value, `SelectedValue` acts a bit differntly as it has to find an item or it will clear the `SelectedItem` on the list.

```
<ListView SelectedValue="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding lstNames1}" />
<ListView SelectedValue="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding lstNames2}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Hope that make sense :)

[image]
[image]